# Problema em Url Amigável

Tags: php, mysql, htaccess, url

Estou aqui com outro problema relativamente a esta linha

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$ index.php?controller=estabelecimentos&option=tipo&tipo=$1 [L]
```

resolveu um problema mas agora tentei criar a mesma linha mas para outro ficheiro mas cai sempre nessa regra estabelecimentos como posso resolver isso ?

Fiheiro htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^comer$ index.php?controller=comer
RewriteRule ^dormir$ index.php?controller=dormir
RewriteRule ^comprar$ index.php?controller=comprar
RewriteRule ^servicos$ index.php?controller=servicos
RewriteRule ^lazer$ index.php?controller=lazer
RewriteRule ^o-que-visitar$ index.php?controller=o-que-visitar
RewriteRule ^contactos$ index.php?controller=contactos
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?controller=login
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$ index.php?controller=estabelecimentos&option=tipo&tipo=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$ index.php?controller=ver_estabelecimento&option=tipo&tipo=$1 [L]
```

Eu tenho na rota estabelecimentos a url a ser fornecida assim http://exemplo.pt/tradicional
eu queria criar outra regra igual mas para ver o estabelecimento correspondente a categoria tradicional mas ficar numa url igual http://exemplo.pt/cafe
fiz uma regra igual ao estabelecimentos, mas para o ficheiro ver_estabelecimento e cai sempre na regra dos estabelecimentos.

Comment: Coloque seu `.htaccess` completo e dê um exemplo de URL.

Comment: Já coloquei acima com exemplo

Comment: @CésarSousa dá o exemplo final que queres para essa url sff

Comment: http://exemplo.pt/cafe

Comment: @CésarSousa A URL final a que ele se refere é a interna que vai carregar o PHP.

Comment: sim so que invés de carregar o ficheiro ver_estabelecimento carrega sempre o estabelecimentos

Comment: @CésarSousa O que é esse "ver_estabelecimento"? Não tem nada disso no seu .htaccess.

Comment: ver_estabelecimento e o ficheiro que vai mostrar o estabelecimento depois de o user escolher a categoria neste caso estabelecimentos eu esqueci de colocar a regra que estava a tentar fazer ja coloquei la

Comment: carrega o mesmo porque o ajax é igual. Tenta alterar a ultima linha por: RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$ index.php?controller=ver_estabelecimento&option=tipo&tipo=$1

Comment: pois mas assim tenho de usar o p antes do nome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode usar duas vezes exatamente o mesmo padrão porque o apache vai considerar apenas o primeiro. Você pode adicionar um `/ver` (ou algo do tipo) no final da URL para diferenciar a operação.

Ex.:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(comer|dormir|comprar|servicos|lazer|o-que-visitar|login)$ index.php?controller=$1 

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)$ index.php?controller=estabelecimentos&option=tipo&tipo=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-0-9-_]+)/ver$ index.php?controller=ver_estabelecimento&option=tipo&tipo=$1
```

Com esta última regra, a URL `http://exemplo.pt/[TIPO]/ver` vai carregar `index.php?controller=ver_estabelecimento&option=tipo&tipo=[TIPO]`

Comment: Então quer dizer que nunca da para usar urls sem o nome do ficheiro

Comment: @CésarSousa Não é possível redirecionar um padrão igual para ações diferentes. Se você realmente não quiser usar a expressão regular ali é só especificar uma regra para cada url diferente. O problema disso é que se esse conteúdo for dinâmico você vai ter que adicionar uma nova regra para cada novo item criado.

Comment: sim o site e dinâmico mas eu conheço um site que utiliza dessa forma e e dinâmico exemplo aqui https://www.zomato.com

Comment: @CésarSousa Esse site usa URLs diferentes para ações diferentes. Para listar os restaurantes de uma categoria, por exemplo, ele usa `/restaurants/internacional` e para ver o item ele usa o nome do restaurante na URL. Deve existir ao menos uma diferença no endereço ou o apache não tem como saber o que fazer.

Comment: mas eu nao noto diferencia nenhuma na url como e possível ainda não percebi muito bem

Comment: @CésarSousa Não entendi. De qual URL você está falando?

Comment: Eles nesse site tem a url https://www.zomato.com/pt/grande-lisboa/top-restaurantes que e a categoria e depois ao escolher o estabelecimento fica assim https://www.zomato.com/pt/grande-lisboa/nome_do_estabelecimento nao muda nada na url para diferenciar no apache

Comment: @CésarSousa Sim, mas você não citou isso na sua pergunta. Como você quer que fique sua URL?

Comment: quero que fique http://exemplo.pt/nome_do_estabelecimento peço desculpa por não me conseguir expressar bem. nome_do_estabelecimento e o nome do estabelecimento

Comment: Pode me dizer entao como posso fazer essa url

Comment: Acho que você deveria utilizar esta regra então mesmo setando o nome do ficheiro, mas crie algo tipo "ver-estabelecimento" assim se mantém prático e otimizado.

Comment: pois isso eu sei dessa forma resolve os meus problemas mas o cliente nao quer usar o nome dos ficheiros so quer que apareca o nome do estabelecimento ou categoria

Comment: so preciso de saber se e possível fazer dessa forma ?

Comment: @CésarSousa Pra ficar dessa forma a lista de estabelecimentos **tem** que ter algo diferente na URL. Com duas regras iguais o apache não vai saber o que é o que.

Comment: entao esse site do exemplo como e que eles fazem, fazem o regra para cada um criado ?

Comment: Prontos eu corrigi o prolema mudando sempre qualquer coisa na regra agora eu queria criar uma regra que desse para dois ficheiros diferentes isso da  ?